# Good practice for using "templated" projects with Git/GitHub

Tags: git, github

As might become apparent when reading this question, I'm still fairly new with Git and GitHub, so please forgive me if I'm not using the right terminology or if what I'm asking is a dumb question.

I use Vue.js and Vuetify for my projects. Recently, I created a base project that I want to use for my future projects as an easy way to get started. The base project serves as a template, as it has all settings and files I want to work with. I created a Git repository and uploaded it to GitHub. I don't intend on changing this repository in any way in the future.

Now, I want to use it for a new project, but I'm not sure how to do it. My first thought was cloning the repository of the base project, deleting the .git file and then creating a new git repository for the new project, using the files from the base project as the initial commit, but it doesn't seem like the right way to do it. I don't want to "fork it" either, as I don't really want to make changes to the base project.

Basically, I want to copy the files from the base project repository, maintain some kind of link to the base project repository (so I know where I got the files from) but start "fresh", with no need to refer to the base project repository again. The base project and the new project don't have to interact from that point onward, so I don't need the new project to pull changes from the base project for example.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Add a note in the README saying "this project was bootstrapped from the template at <url of the template repo>"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option (and there are probably very many) is to create your new project(s) as blank projects - maybe with an initial commit with a readme or .gitignore or somthing. Then add your "base" repo as another remote and merge it in. For example:

```
mkdir derived_proj
cd derived_proj
git init
touch readme.md
git add readme.md
git commit -am "Initial commit"
git remote add base <url-to-base>
git fetch base
git pull base master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

The last three lines are the key lines here, everything before that is just setting up a blank repo (but if you use gitlab or whatever then just use that to setup your new repo).

So here we are creating a repo with some initial commit. Then we add the base repo as a remote and then merge it in. The base repo is unchanged and the idea is that you will never push to it (Could even protect that so no one can accidentally do that).

But you will have the history of the base repo. So it could look like this:

```
*   70bd2be (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'master' of ../big_array
|\  
| * 6f0f769 (base/master) added instruction
| * 82a54b6 updated with some results in the readme
| * 6f57491 initial working version
| * ecba7af added readme
| * ef8689e added make utils. Updated gitignore
| * b046678 First commit - working code
* f7e79cb updated test
* 2aeec74 init commit
```

You can see here that the `master` branch has the ancestor of the `base/master` branch from the base repo.

You can remove the base repo for further safety:

`git remote remove base`

Which results in:

```
*   70bd2be (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'master' of ../big_array
|\  
| * 6f0f769 added instruction    <----- NO BASE REMOTE
| * 82a54b6 updated with some results in the readme
| * 6f57491 initial working version
| * ecba7af added readme
| * ef8689e added make utils. Updated gitignore
| * b046678 First commit - working code
* f7e79cb updated test
* 2aeec74 init commit
```

That way you are protected. But if you keep the base repo, you could then pull any changes you make to the base at a later date - although you said that it would most likely not change - you never know...

**update**

Just in case you don't want the entire history you could do:

```
git remote add base <url-to-base>
git fetch base
git pull base master --allow-unrelated-histories --squash
git commit -am "Added/pulled base->master"    <---- NEED TO COMMIT
git remote remove base
```

Then you have just merged in base in a single commit and that commit is all you will see. Note you need to commit after the pull because of `--squash`.

Comment: Finally got around to trying it out myself and it worked wonderfully! Many thanks. (I used the commands from your update, since I didn't want to keep the history, I don't know about the other commands)